# Add dynamic layout to xml in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

My main activity code is :

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/Container"> </LinearLayout>
```

And My dynamic layout code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    sv.addView(ll);


    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Dynamic layouts ftw!");
    ll.addView(tv);

    EditText et = new EditText(this);
    et.setText("weeeeeeeeeee~!");
    ll.addView(et);

    Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setText("I don't do anything, but I was added dynamically. :)");
    ll.addView(b);

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
        cb.setText("I'm dynamic!");
        ll.addView(cb);
    }
    this.setContentView(sv);
}
```

i want to add the dynamically coded View inside the LinearLayout with Id=Container. How to do that

Answer (score 0):

Remove the part with

```
this.setContentView(sv);
```

Replace with:

```
setContentView(R.layout.<layout_name>);

ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.Container);
container.addView(sv);
```

I see you do not set any layout parameters. you may want to do that.

Comment: thnks bro that helped alot

Comment: How to add different params to the layout. I've created textView and added param of parent layout but i want to add some other params to it. how to do that

Comment: Please read the documentation. this is too much to get into here.

Answer (score 0):

```
 LinearLayout linearlayoutinxml = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.Container); 
 // then you add your custom view
 linearlayoutinxml.addView(sv);
 setContentView(linearlayoutinxml);
```

Comment: thnks bro for helping